# Insert NULL into setDouble method Java

Tags: java, oracle

My code attempting to insert NULL into setDouble method in PreparedStatement

```
ps.setDouble(++i, balance.getAmount());
```

**getAmount() is Double field**.

i am able to handle like

```
if (balance.getAmount() ==  null ) {
    ps.setNull(++i, java.sql.Types.NULL);
}else{
    ps.setDouble(++i, balance.getAmount());
}
```

But my code looks ugly, because my code have many number of setInt setLong setDouble methods.

Is there any way to hanlde smartly or is there any other approach. Please advise me.

Comment: Any reason to not use primitive `double`?

Comment: It is inserting default values 0 instead of null.

Comment: You can use some library to manage that for you. Spring JdbcTemplate for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would extract the ugliness into helper methods

```
class StatementHelper{
    static void setDouble(int index, PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Double val) throws SQLException {
        if (val == null )
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.NULL);
        else
            preparedStatement.setDouble(index, val);
    }

    //Repeat for other data types
}
```

and then just build your statement like that

```
StatementHelper.setDouble(++i, ps, balance);
StatementHelper.setInt(++i, ps, someInt);
StatementHelper.setString(++i, ps, someString);
StatementHelper.setFloat(++i, ps, someFloat);
```

This would keep the statement building code relatively clean

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
preparedStatement.setObject(i, balance.getAmount(), java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
```

[setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-int-)